# Want to show small part of js Bar Chart when value is zero

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have these bar charts that will sometimes show zero values to the user.  I'd like to show a bit of the bar chart so it does not look completely empty, but the data is connected to the visual representation of the bar.  Is there any way I could have the top number say zero but the value be 3(or something small) in each column?  Here is the code and a screenshots. One screenshot has data, the other is zero. I'd like the zero graph to show just a bit of the orange and green when at zero. Thanks
[image][image]

```
<canvas id="bar-chart" width="900" height="350"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx = document.getElementById("bar-chart");
debugger;
var data = {
  labels: ["Page Views", "Data Requests"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [<?php echo $databaseClass->totalViewsSelectedMonth($user_id, $year, 1);

      ?>, <?php 
      echo $databaseClass->isRfYearMonth($user_id, $year, 1);
      ?>],
    backgroundColor: ["orange", "green"]
  }]
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    "hover": {
      "animationDuration": 0
    },
    "animation": {
      "duration": 1,
      "onComplete": function() {
        var chartInstance = this.chart,
          ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
            var data = dataset.data[index];
            ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
          });
        });
      }
    },
    legend: {
      "display": false
    },
    tooltips: {
      "enabled": false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: false,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          max: Math.max(...data.datasets[0].data) + 20,
          display: false,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [you can update the axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#updating-axis-defaults) of your charts to a new default.  So, using a modified form of their example, something like the following (modified to fit your code):

```
// ...
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        display: false,
        gridLines: {
            display: false
        },
        ticks: {
            max: Math.max(...data.datasets[0].data) + 20,
            min: -3, // ADDED
            display: false,
            beginAtZero: true
        }
    }],
// ...
```

... would do what you're looking for - with the side benefit that 0 and 3 wouldn't look like the same value, the relative bar size should stay accurate.

Comment: Ahh looks like this might work.  Let me try it and get back to you.  One sec

Comment: so I added min -3 and when value is zero it still shows nothing.  What you're saying makes sense however, if the graph starts in the negative a zero should show.  Maybe I should take away beginAtZero or change display to true?

Comment: Strange, so If I put min -6 and the value at -2 you see some of the bar, but if value set at zero with min -6 you see same as before, no bar at all?

Comment: Are you certain that you're actually passing in data if the value is zero?  Any chance the data is being omitted altogether?

Comment: Yea @Jason nothing I do seems to work? Thanks for the help though. If you can think of any solutions let me know and I'll gladly give you the answer.

Comment: Yes I put actual zeros to test it and still not working.

Comment: doesn't even make sense?